# How to include show more button for fullcalendar timegrid views(day/week)?

Tags: events, fullcalendar

I need to limit the number of events displayed in time grid week or time grid day in fullcalendar. I have found the option called " dayMaxEvents" in fullcalendar documentation. But it is only limiting the events in a month view. How can I limit the events in day view and week view ?

I saw many questions regarding the same but no answer was found.

Is it possible to limit the count in day/ week view ?
I am getting like this :

[image]

[image]

Comment: No it's not possible. If you want to make them less wide you can set the `https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap` option to `true`. If you want to get a better feature than you can consider making a feature request or voting for an existing one, if someone has asked for it before. Maybe you can even offer to contribute the necessary code yourself. See https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features for details.

Comment: Okay , So you are telling like no current option is available in fullcalendar to limit the number of events and show "more " button in day / week view like in month view right ? The slot event overlap option is there, but when number of events are large for a particular time say above 6 or 10, then again it seems like congested. So thats why thought of showing 4 or 5 and display the "more " button. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: That's correct there is no option available.